# Delayed Job not saving new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have trying to save a new record with delayed job. The code in question is below:

```
#method being called:
ibo.add_to_database(params[:url])

#method definition
def add_to_database(url)
  feed = Feeds.new do |f|
    f.url = url
    f.title = self.feed_title if self.feed_title
    f.link = self.site_link if self.site_link
    f.image = self.feed_image if self.feed_image
  end
  feed.save!
end
handle_asynchronously :add_to_database
```

I get absolutely no errors, and the job is removed from the database as it should be. Except there is no change to the Feeds model. Anyone have any ideas what gives?

Comment: What are you checking for errors?

Comment: I have executed the code without delayed job, and it works perfectly. With delayed_job, given an error a failed attempt should be registered with the job in the database. This is not happening...

Comment: Any update on this, I have the exact same scenario and I am getting Delayed::DeserializationError.

Answer (score 2):

delayed_job runs as a daemon thread, so the first thing to do would be to check whether that it is running:

```
ps ax | grep delayed_job
```

the next thing I would check the log of actual delayed job, it would probably have you error description:

```
less log/delayed_job.log
```

Other then that, your code sniplet looks fine.